# mongoose reference to array like array[0] in find filter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I had a weird issue. I've been using mongodb and mongoose for sometime and never had an array filtering. Today I had to do it and I'm stuck.

How do you access array stored in mondodb using the traditional way array[0]?

My array stored in my db as the following:

```
_id:6262013fa90e7b533809140d
isactive:true
schedule:Array

1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
5:Object
6:Object
name:"whatever"
description:"describe somthing"
```

so many questions about mongoose arrays online and yet the doc is not showing any examples.

So now if I want to access the array schedule[0] value. How do I filter the find({"schedule[0]" : "object.name"})

Or how do you access arrays in general in Mongoose? The doc is so poor and no examples about it online.

How do I update schedule[2] or schedule[3] in that array using mongoose?

schedule[0] object has the following data:

```
0:Object
weekdayname:"Monday",weekdaynumber:1,
openhours:"10",
closehours:"10"
openminutes:"00"
closeminutes:"00"
openampm:"AM",closeampm:"PM"
```

to update schedule[0].openhours, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

**Query**

```
db.collection.find({
  "schedule.weekdayname": "Monday"
},
{
  "schedule.$": 1
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xyPfDS2d-t1)

[mongoose find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

---

**Update**

```
db.collection.update({
  "schedule.weekdayname": "Monday"
},
{
  $set: {
    "schedule.$.openhours": "11"
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q0ON91au_4J)

[mongoose update](https://%20https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html)

Comment: Thank you YuTing for replying. I'm unable to make it work. I added the object details inside my array. So my array first element [0] has openhours which accepts a string.  so how to update this: schedule[0].openhours , also I'm using mongoose, is it different from mongodb?

Comment: @Marco I update my answer

Comment: Thank you for editing my question to clarify the object properties. what is the $ in "schedule.$.openhours"?